# How to use SendKeys as Pause break?

Tags: vbscript

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{BREAK}"
```

I want run as <kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> keys, How can I set it?

Comment: Given that pause/break is a single key, how does what you posted not do what you want?

Comment: yes, how can I sendkeys with this key?

Comment: It might depend on the shell you're connected to.  For me, it was `[CLEAR]` to send the pause key.